# Restoring removed commits in SVN

Tags: svn, restore, revert

I've removed a commit from trunk, for example commit 100:

```
svn -r 100:99 .
```

and I've committed the change so that revision 100 is no longer in trunk. Is there a way to put revision 100 back into trunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Revert the commit that reverted 100. For example if you did this in commit 123, then:

```
svn merge -c -123 .
```

Comment: thanks! I was missing the '-' before the revision number